# Play audio file when someone joins voice channel

Tags: discord.js

I followed some tutorials and got some help, but no matter what I try it keeps showing an error with the `playFile`. The bot can also play music but the music (through a link) part works fine. So how would I play an audio file that's in the root folder and only when someone joins the voice channel?

```js
bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {

// Here I'm storing the IDs of their voice channels, if available
let oldChannel = oldMember.voiceChannel ? oldMember.voiceChannel.id : null;
let newChannel = newMember.voiceChannel ? newMember.voiceChannel.id : null;
if (oldChannel === newChannel) return; // If there has been no change, exit

// Here I'm getting the bot's channel (bot.voiceChannel does not exist)
let botMember = oldMember.guild.member(bot.user),
    botChannel = botMember ? botMember.voiceChannel.id : null;

var server = servers[botMember.guild.id];

// Here I'm getting the channel, just replace VVV this VVV with the channel's ID
let textChannel = oldMember.guild.channels.get('438025505615249408');
if (!textChannel) throw new Error("That channel does not exist.");

// Here I don't need to check if they're the same, since it would've exit before
if (newChannel === botChannel) {
    // console.log("A user joined.");

    server.dispatcher = botMember.voiceConnection.playFile('./audiofile.mp3');

    textChannel.send(newMember.displayName + " joined.");

} else if (oldChannel === botChannel) {
    // console.log("A user left.");
    textChannel.send(newMember.displayName + " left.");
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note: you're using `GuildMember.voiceConnection`, but that property does not exist. Look a the docs for [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember).

The docs for [`VoiceConnection.playFile()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=playFile) say that the `file` argument has to be an absolute path (like `C:/yourfolder/audio.mp3`). To convert a relative path (`./audio.mp3`) to an absolute one, you need to join the directory (stored in the global variable `__dirname`) and the relative:

```js
let conn = bot.voiceConnections.get(newMember.guild.id);
if (!conn) throw new Error("The bot is not in a voiceChannel, fix your code.");

let path = __dirname + '/audiofile.mp3';
conn.playFile(path);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `path` module ([docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html)).

```js
let path = require('path').join(__dirname, './audiofile.mp3');
conn.playFile(path);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You also helped me yesterday but I seem to have a problem with the bot when the bot itself leaves. The consoles shows a probleme with botChannel = botMember ? botMember.voiceChannel.id : null; and it point as the. Id part

Comment: let conn = bot.voiceConnections.get(Message.guild.id); has an error that says Message is not defined

Comment: First comment: if there's an error it means that the bot is not in any voice channel.Second comment: it's not `Message`, it's `message`; variables are case sensitive

Comment: @Waldre I didn't see that it was in `voiceStateUpdate`, my bad. I've edited my answer

Comment: oh xD thanks, works perfect now. It just has one more problem and its when the bot leaves the voice channel is stops working and says it has a problem with 'botChannel = botMember ? botMember.voiceChannel.id : null;' and points at the .id part

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the problem by adding an if statement to only get the bots id if its in a voiceChannel

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was going to write ;)

Comment: Now it just skips it every time and doesn't say if someone joined.

Comment: Are you making it join the channel?

Comment: yes, it joins the channel but when it leaves the channel it stops working and says TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: like when I type a command to have it exit. It just stops working completly and says TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined and its for this line 'let botChannel = botMember ? botMember.voiceChannel.id : null;'

Comment: Ok, final fix. I made a var botA = false. so when I do the join command botA = true, when I do the leave command botA = false. Then only if botA is true it will set the botChannel. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)